# How do I change the front-end language in Magento 1.9.3.6?

Tags: admin, frontend, language, magento-1.9.3.6

I have made a **Webshop** and I want that the store can be seen in different languages: **English, Dutch, and Turkish**. The admin language should stay **English**.

I don't know how this works. I tried this already but when I try this I am only able to see the front-end site in Dutch but when I change the language to **English** or **Turkish** I get the message

> There was no Home CMS page configured or found.

Comment: Please check your CMS > Homepage. Your Home page is assigned to only one store. Please make sure its selected for all store view.